# Calculating the volume under the surface $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, area, volume

> I have to calculate the volume under the surface 
>   $$f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$

I have no clue what to do, but I'm just using the integration I learned.

I take a little slice, and the area of that slice should be 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx$$

Then, I have to evaluate this slice for each $y$, so I have to take the integral of this integral, if it makes sense or something...

So I got 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$

I have no clue how to evaluate the integral, but I punched this exact expression into a calculator and got 3.1415926..., so I think I did something meaningful...

Does what I did work, find the area of a slice for some random $y$ and integrate that slice area expression from $y=-\infty$ to $y=+\infty$??

> **Update:** How do I switch this into polar coordinates?

Comment: switch to polar coordinates

Comment: how do I do that @WillJagy

Comment: Have you considered converting to polar coordinates?

Comment: i don't know how to do that @amd

Comment: The translation from $(x, y)$ to $(r, \theta)$ is to plug in $r\cos\theta$ for $x$ everywhere you see it, $r\sin\theta$ for $y$ every time you see it, and $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta$.  You have to figure out the bounds for $r$ and $\theta$, but in this case, the radius goes from $0$ to $\infty$ and the angle goes from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Note that $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ and $dxdy = rdrd\theta$. Proving the latter fact is not trivial, but not overly difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, thus
$$
J = \det\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
 \cos\theta  & -r\sin\theta \\
 \sin\theta   &   r\cos \theta
\end{vmatrix}
=r\cos^2\theta + r \sin^2 \theta = r(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r.
$$
Now, as you don't have any restrictions, your integration region is given by
 $$
D=\{(r\cos\theta, r\sin \theta) | 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \le r < \infty\},$$
$$
\int \int e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^\infty e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta= -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (e^{-r^2}|^{\infty}_{0} d\theta =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}  d\theta = \pi,
$$
where in the third step, one can see that $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}e^{-r^2}=-2re^{-r^2}$, thus 
$$\int e^{-r^2} r dr = -1/2\int(-2) e^{-r^2} rdr  = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-r^2}+C. 
$$

Comment: Where did that -1/2 come from??

Comment: Hi, pls see the edited answer.